# Exporting PDF > HTML with Acrobat Pro, all special chars showing ? despite apparent UTF-8 encoding.

Tags: pdf, encoding, utf-8, acrobat

I have a set of PDFs that I am exporting to HTML files using the HTML 4.01 export option. When I open the files in SublimeText or Chrome, all special characters are showing as a ?. The declared encoding is UTF-8:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/strict.dtd">
 <!-- Created from PDF via Acrobat SaveAsXML -->
 <!-- Mapping table version: 28-February-2003 -->
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

The problem persists if I use the SublimeText "Save with encoding-" option, and save with UTF-8. 
The odd thing is that this only happening with some PDFs. Others are saving with the correct encoding, but there is no difference in the export process. Is there anything I can check for in the PDF files themselves, or in the export process, to look into this?

Comment: *"anything I can check"* -- as usual: if you select this text in Acrobat, copy and paste it into e.g. Notepad, do you get text as expected?

Comment: Yes, if I cope the text from the PDF to Notepad, I get the expected characters.